# Mongodb an object representing an expression must have exactly one field when using $cond, $size and $in in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to work out for each country how many times the UK appears with the following query:

```
    db.movies.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$countries"},
    {$group:{_id:"$countries", total : { $sum: {$cond: [ {
    "countries": {"$in" : ["UK", ["$countries"]], "$not" : { "$size" : 1.0}}}, 1, 0]}}}},
    {$match: { total: { $gte: 10 }}}
    ])
```

which gives me an object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $in: [ "UK", [ "$countries" ] ], $not: { $size: 1.0 } }", although when I try the part giving me problems just by itself with a find it works fine:

```
db.movies.find(
{ "countries" : { "$in" : ["UK", ["$countries"]], "$not" : { "$size" : 1}}}, 
{ "_id" : 0, "countries" : 1});
```

result:

```
{ "countries" : [ "UK", "New Zealand" ] }
{ "countries" : [ "USA", "UK" ] }
{ "countries" : [ "UK", "USA", "France" ] }
{ "countries" : [ "UK", "USA" ] }
{ "countries" : [ "USA", "UK" ] }
{ "countries" : [ "UK", "Italy" ] }...
```

Comment: Reduce your failing code. Find another, simpler query where you can use expressions, and test your expression without $group.

Comment: @D.SM hello, I tried taking out the expression causing the trouble but it runs fine by itself(see the last section of my question) it just fails when used within the condition. Do you know why?

Comment: I think `$size` is misused there.  Passing 2 criteria to the `$cond` might require explicitly using `$and`

Comment: Your failing expression is $sum($cond(field($in))). Your working expression is field($in). You are missing one more step in arriving at the root of the problem which is testing $cond(field($in)).

Comment: @Joe I tried it that way and again it works outside of the condition but gives me a new error "Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: double"

Comment: @D.SM not sure how to do that, could you give me an example query to test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most confusing aspects of MongoDB is that it contains 2 contexts, the Mongo Query Language, and the Aggregation Framework.  There are operators that exist in both, but have very different syntax and action in each context.

The MQL is used in `find` filter expressions, and in `$match` expressions in an aggregation pipeline.

Aggregation expressions are used throughout the rest of the pipeline, and may be used in `find` or `$match` as part of an [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#expr) expression.

Confused yet?

Good, so was I when I first saw those.

I see 3 problems with the query provided:

1. An object is passed to `$cond` instead of a boolean expression
2. MQL expressions being used where an aggregation expression is needed
3. Applying array operations to a string value.

#### 1. $cond

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#size), $cond has the following form:

```
{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }
```

In your exmaple, the `<boolean-expression>` is

```
{"countries": {"$in" : ["UK", ["$countries"]], "$not" : { "$size" : 1.0}}}
```

That is a valid query object for the Mongo Query Language, but it is *not* a boolean expression.  I'll come back to that in moment.

#### 2a. $size

[$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#size) as an MQL operator matches any array with the number of elements specified by the argument.  The usage in your query is consistent with using `$size` as this operator.

However, in a `$cond` expression inside of a `$group` stage, the aggregation form of the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html#size-aggregation) operator should be used.  In this context `$size` counts and returns the total number of items in an array. i.e. not a boolean expression.

Inside of the `$cond` expression, to test if the size of the `countries` array is not equal to 1, use:

```
{$ne: [{$size:"$countries"},1]}
```

### 2b. $in

When using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#in) as an MQL operator, the syntax is:

```
{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }
```

When using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html#in-aggregation) as an aggregation operator, the syntax is:

```
{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }
```

In this query, to test if the `countries` array contains "UK", use:

```
{$in: ["UK", "$countries"]}
```

### $cond + $size + $in + $and

To combine these all together, use the [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/index.html#and-aggregation) operator:

```
{$cond: [
    {$and: [
        {$in: ["UK", "$countries"]},
        {$ne: [{$size:"$countries"},1]}
    ]},
    1,
    0
]}
```

#### 3. Array operators

The `$unwind` stage will explode the array so that each document passed to the following pipeline stages contains only one element from the original array.  Thus the field `countries` in the documents passed to the `$group` stage will be a single string value, not an array.

To test this, run the aggregation with just the `$unwind` stage, and examine the results.

#### **EDIT**

Based on the statements in the comments, the goal is to count the occurrences of each other country that appears in an array that also contains "UK".  To accomplish this, use the following aggregation stages:

- $match to select only documents that contain "UK" in the array
- $unwind the array so each element can be considered separately
- $match to eliminate "UK" documents from the steam
- $group by country and count the number of occurrences

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {$match: {countries: "UK"}},
  {$unwind: "$countries"},
  {$match: {countries: {$ne: "UK"}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$countries",
      count: {$sum: 1}
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xCwrOeLv5lm)

Comment: Hey thanks Joe, when I try your and condition I get "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: string" and "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: string"

Comment: Do you know how to perform something like an unwind but still retain the array when checking that field?

Comment: What's the goal of this query?

Comment: To get a list of each country and how many times the UK appears alongside. The reason I included not size of one was to exclude UK from the list.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you don't need `$cond` or `$size` at all.